# Unit testing Blobstore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to unit test some of the codes that use Blobstore API, however I am getting `NullPointerException` for this code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:service/client-config.xml" })
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class BlobstoreDaoTest {
        private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
                new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());
        private final LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig  config = 
                new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig();

        @Autowired
        private BlobstoreDao dao;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            config.setUp();
            helper.setUp();
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() {
            helper.tearDown();
            config.tearDown();
        }

        @Test
        public void doTest() {
         // Code omitted
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig.setUp(LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig.java:52)
```

Comment: The helper should contain all of the configs and only its setUp/tearDown are called. The local blobstore probably doesn't see that the datastore is setup, since its outside of its context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is something along these lines:

```
public class BlobstoreDaoTest {
    private LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(
              new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig(),
              new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig()
            );

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }
...
```